# ScrollView a TableLayout inside a TabHost

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am trying to scroll a TableLayout that is nested inside a Tab. I can scroll the Table as intended but the problem is that the Table when scrolls up, it shows up behind the Tab as it scrolls.

I want to make just the Table part of the Layout to scroll.

At the end there is a RelativeLayout which serves as a legend(Key Guide) of the information that I will show dynamically in the form of rows inside the Table. SO it needs to be at the bottom of the screen and should not scroll like the table itself. But in this code everything below the Tab scrolls up (except the RelativeLayout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical">

//Fixed On Screen

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

//Fixed On Screen

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp" >

                <TextView
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/start"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/effect"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

//Scroll this content inside the Tab ONLY

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" >
                </TableLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" >
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>

//Fixed On Screen at the very bottom so the area between this and Tab is what scrolls

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/excellent"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Good"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/dark_gray"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/normal"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Bad"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In short, I want the following to be fixed on screen:

- The Tab
- The First TableLayout
- The Last RelativeLayout

And want only the middle FrameLayout/TableLayout to Scroll. This layout will be filled with rows dynamically.

I have a feeling that it is as simple as maybe a `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` maybe. But can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks!